# require sqlite3 error in ruby upon starting server

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am trying to install a ruby app on my local machine, I am trying to start the rails server command, but I get a long list of errors despite having installed the proper gems (or at least I think so)

I'm just copying the first few lines of my error here:

```
alex@alex-crunchbang:~/Documents/myapp$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-  3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

What could be the cause of my problem? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `bundle install` before starting Rails.

Comment: Could you create a new Gemset in rvm (`rvm 1.8.7@newgemset --createa`) and run `bundle install` again? Does it install all the gems, including the `sqlite3` gem? Also: is `sqlite3` present in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: cool, i could get rid of most errors - now if to start i try to  thinking sphinx (which i have to do before starting my serve, ive been told) i just get a Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/alex/Documents/myapp/log/searchd.log. so i guess you solved my main error! :D